# Seeking lists of words formed from an existing word

Tags: word, wordplay, reference-request

Where is a resource that lists words that can become another word with the addition of one letter while still maintaining the order of the letters? For example, adding an "I" to SLANDER creates the word ISLANDER. FRIGHT becomes FREIGHT.

I have found a variety of websites but they only offer 3-5 letter words. I'm looking for more challenging words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Qat](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=AB%3BA.B%3B%7CA%7C%3D0-%3B%7CAB%7C%3D7-&ent=Search&dict=4) with a query like

```
AB;A.B;|A|=0-;|AB|=7
```

Explanation:

A and B are by default non-empty strings.

```
AB
```

The concatenation of A and B forms a word.

```
A.B
```

The concatenation of A, any letter, and B forms a word.

```
|A|=0-
```

The length of A is at least 0. This allows A to be empty. I haven't allowed B to be empty to forbid simple one-letter suffix additions like s, d, or r.

```
|AB|=7-
```

The total length of A and B is at least 7.

Comment: What a neat site! `A;A[!sdr];|A|=7-` finds one-letter suffix additions, excluding s,d,r.
Some fun ones are `flamingO`, `crotchetY`, `directorY`, and `harmonicA`.

Comment: As Tom said, "What a neat site!"  This is exactly what I was looking for.  If I may impose upon you again, what would be the syntax to search for words that form two words when spelled forward and backward (not palindromes)? For example, REWARD and DRAWER.  TIA

Comment: @BobBaerker [A;~A;|A|=6](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=A%3B%7EA%3B%7CA%7C%3D6&ent=Search&dict=4)

Comment: @BobBaerker please do not ask completely separate questions in the comments. Instead, ask new questions in the question box!

Comment: This was a request for further information based on the answer received.  Asking a separate question would lead to discontinuity.

Comment: @BobBaerker quite the opposite! You can ask a new question and link to this answer, and then *a link will be automatically put into the sidebar for this page*. Separately you can tag the new question with [tag:quinaplus] increasing the connectivity between related questions!

Comment: Also the pattern in [your comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115381/seeking-lists-of-words-formed-from-an-existing-word/115383#comment322389_115383) is completely separate from the one in the answer... bobble is not amonishing you, but helping you follow the best practices here. Take a look at the [tour], and read through [ask] for more info

Comment: @PuzzlingFerret - I don't feel admonished.  I've been around Stack long enough to understand how it works.  With all due respect, turning such an insignificant comment request for additional information into a new question is inefficient and far from best practices, other than following rigid rules.  Be that as it may, you are entitled to your opinion.

Comment: That objective is fine for a purist but after wasting a lot of time viewing many web sites which eneded up offering little to nothing, I'm thrilled to have found a site that provides all word combos, even if it includes palindromes.  There aren't a heckuva a lot of them so deleting them is no bother at all :->).  Happy to have found this board.  The English board didn't like this question (LOL).

Comment: @BobBaerker I think the fundamental disagreement here is whether asking how to use a tool to do a completely different thing than the original question is a new question or simply addition information. Anyways, one big reason that asking a new question is better is the length limitation of comments. To properly answer your new question, a much longer answer is needed (longer than the one you got...), unless one is willing to forgo all explanation of why the answer is correct.

Comment: @BobBaerker IMO what you did wasn't wrong, but in retrospect I think the [extra question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/115403/48337) provides a lot more value, not only for further explanation, as bobble mentioned, but also for considering multiple solutions and making it easier for others to find the Q&A in the future. After all, the philosophy of Stack Exchange is to collect high-quality answers, not just for you searching today, but for everyone like you who comes searching tomorrow.