# Seeking a list of words formed from existing words

Tags: word, wordplay, reference-request, quinapalus

Recently, I asked for some assistance on [word formation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115381/seeking-lists-of-words-formed-from-an-existing-word/115383?noredirect=1#comment322445_115383).  The respondent provided me with the [Qat website](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=AB%3BA.B%3B%7CA%7C%3D0-%3B%7CAB%7C%3D7-&ent=Search&dict=4) which was perfect.  I have another question.

I would like to generate a list of words where two smaller words form a larger word.  For example, adding SHIP to FRIEND, LORD, and WAR creates the words FRIENDSHIP, LORDSHIP, and WARSHIP.

Answer (score 4):

In Qat this is [`A;B;AB`](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=A%3BB%3BAB&ent=Search&dict=4):

- `A` is a string of letters which must be a word
- `B` is a string of letters which must be a word
- `AB` (those two concatenated) is a string of letters which must be a word

If you would like to force longer words, simply add length constraints, e.g. [`A;B;AB;|A|=4-;|B|=2-`](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=A%3BB%3BAB%3B%7CA%7C%3D4-%3B%7CB%7C%3D2-&ent=Search&dict=4)

Comment: Your coding generated the list but at first glance, it wasn't a perfect solution.  But then I alphabetically sorted the second word to group them and it gave me the result that I sought. Thank you!

Comment: The fun ones are those were the meanings change, and of the longer word combinations I really like troubles+hooting and pronoun+cements.